# How to assert click precedence of overlapping buttons?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

This code below is silly, but it represents a concept that I'm trying to understand.  There are 2 buttons that overlap.  When I click on the top button only the bottom button's click event is fired.  Is there a way to force the top button's click to register instead of the bottom button in the overlapping area?

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="TopButton" Click="TopButton_Click" Content="Top Button" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button x:Name="BottomButton" Click="BottomButton_Click" Content="I am the Bottom Button I am very wide" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where is the silly code?

Comment: Sorry @shole, it's been a rough week.  Added now.

Comment: Have you tried to change the order in which you have defined your buttons, or specify *Canvas.ZIndex*?

Comment: That's it @Romasz!  I tried Zindex several times but was trying to put it on the BUTTON itself!   Please post this as a separate item and I"ll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should work if you specify the correct order of your buttons, either by first defining bottom button or by setting suitable *Canvas.ZIndex*. As I think the topmost button should fire (with the biggest *ZIndex*), and as I've tried this should work:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="TopButton" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Click="TopButton_Click" Content="Top Button" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button x:Name="BottomButton" Canvas.ZIndex="0" Click="BottomButton_Click" Content="I am the Bottom Button I am very wide" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

As a side note - it's probably not a good practice to put buttons one on the other.

Comment: Of course not, but there's a 3rd part accordion control and I'm trying to put a tiny button at the far left of the huge collapse button to "lock" it.  Strange, but the client is insisting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand is

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Button x:Name="TopButton" Click="TopButton_Click" Content="Top Button" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<Button x:Name="BottomButton" Click="BottomButton_Click" Content="I am the Bottom Button I am very wide" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

The above code will work like a stack, so when you add the top button its first rendered on the screen and then the bottom button, so always the one which was rendered later will be on the top and will be clicked, just change the steps and render the button which u want it on the top.